# How does solr work with data split into different services and therefore not synchronously available?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, indexing, dih

take for instance an ecommerce store with catalog and price data in different web services. Now, we know that solr does not allow partial updates to a document field([JIRA bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-139)), so how do you index these two services  ?
I had three possibilities, but I'm not sure which one is correct:

1. Partial update - not possible
2. Solr join - have price and catalog in separate index and join them **in solr**. You cant join them in your client side code, without screwing up pagination and facet counts. I dont know if this is possible in pre-solr 4.0
3. have some sort of intermediate indexing service, which composes an entire document based on the results from both these services and sends this for indexing. however there are two problems with this approach:

   3.1 You can still compose documents partially, and then when the document is complete, you can set a flag indicating that this is a complete document. However, to do this each time a document has to be indexed, it has to first check whether the document exists in the index, edit it and push it back. So, big performance hit.
   3.2 Your intermediate service checks whether a particular id is available from all services - if not silently drops it and hopes that when it appears in the other service, the first service will already be populated. This is OK, but it means that an item is not available in search until all fields are available (not desirable always - if u dont have price, you can simply set it to out-of-stock and still have it available)

Of all these methods, only #3.2 looks viable to me - does anyone know how you do this kind of thing with DIH? Because now, you have two different entry points (2 different web services) into indexing and each has to check the other

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to solve this is close to your 3.2: write code that creates the document you want to index from the different available services. The usual flow would be to fetch all the items from the catalog, then fetch the prices when indexing. Wether you want to have items in the search from the catalog that doesn't have prices available depends on your business rules for the service. If you want to speed up the process (fetch product, fetch price, repeat), expand the API to fetch 1000 products and then prices for all the products at the same time.

There is no reason why you should drop an item from the index if it doesn't have price, unless you don't want items without prices in your index. It's up to you and your particular need what kind of information you need to have available before indexing the document.

As far as I remember 4.0 will probably support partial updates as it moves to the new abstraction layer for the index files, although I'm not sure it'll make your situation that much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 3.2 is the most common, though I think about it slightly differently. First, think about what you want in your search results, then create one Solr document for each potential result, with as much information as you can get. If it is OK to have a missing price, then add the document that way.

You may also want to match the documents in Solr, but get the latest data for display from the web services. That gives fresh results and avoids skew between the batch updates to Solr and the live data.

Don't hold your breath for fine-grained updates to be added to Solr and Lucene. It gets a lot of its speed from not having record-level locking and update.

Comment: once u add the document with the missing pieces, how do u update it? is it a question of every different service pushing its CHANGELIST ids and then you aggregate data from everywhere and push to solr. or do u retrieve the document from solr, update it and push it back. can u do this kind of aggregation from DIH, or do you have to write your own code (which I prefer anyways) - I'm not able to wrap my head around how do u structure your aggregator.. as a cron, a different webservice, etc.